# "Over the Garden Wall" - What does the title refer to?

Tags: title, over-the-garden-wall

I've recently just seen the TV mini-series *"Over the Garden Wall"*, and I can't figure out what exactly the title was referring to.

I thought about this a lot, and the closest candidate for the titular *Garden Wall* was in Episode 9, when the two half-brothers climb over a shrubberied wall fencing a graveyard. However, that wall was *nowhere* near a garden, so what is the title referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TVTropes explains](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/OverTheGardenWall):

> The title references how Wirt and Greg are **visitors in a strange land**,
>   but has a much more literal meaning. Right before ending up in the
>   Unknown, **Wirt and Greg climbed over the wall of a cemetery—one called
>   "Eternal Garden".**

Answer (score 3):

It's a metaphor for the children leaving a safe and familiar environment and going on an adventure.

The garden (US, back yard) references the world that they know, and the wall is the barrier between that world and a world that they don't know. So they're crossing a barrier to adventure.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "Over the Garden Wall" has some precedent that may be referred to.  Per ​["By the Milk-Light of Moon": Myths and Meanings of "Over the Garden Wall," Part One](https://observationdeck.kinja.com/by-the-milk-light-of-moon-myths-and-meanings-of-ov-1657185829),

> It should be noted that there were three movies prior to the show called Over the Garden Wall. At least two of them were romances about a man and a woman who glimpse each other over, yes, the garden wall and fall in love. However, the more telling appearance of the phrase "over the garden wall" comes from a children's rope-skipping poem:
>
> Over the garden wall
>
> I let the baby fall.
>
> My mother came out
>
> And gave me a clout
>
> Over the garden wall.

The theme of being responsible for one's sibling is the primary subtext between the two main characters, Wirt and Gregory, and there's a literal falling over the garden wall involved. In general the [show draws directly from 19th-20th century folklore](http://www.mdpi.com/2076-0787/5/3/51/htm) as well, so it's unlikely the title is unrelated to this precedent.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it might reference the poem by "September" by Grace Paley:

> Then the flowers became very wild
> because it was early September
> and they had nothing to lose
> they tossed their colors every
> which way **over the garden wall**
> splattering the lawn shoving their
> wild orange red rain-disheveled faces
> into my window without shame

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! Why do you think it might be a reference to this poem? Does it match the events of the series in any way?